# How to check validity of post URL and get post-id using Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

For example I have a link of my post: https://www.facebook.com/yaroslav.decik/posts/266508563391866
First question - is in Facebook API any ways to check validity of post URL using Facebook API (php)?
Second question - is in Facebook API any ways to get from this URL it's post-id using Facebook API (php)?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "validity"?

Comment: Also - are these posts being created by users who have authenticated your application?

Comment: @Lix: by "validity" I mean - to check the existing of this post and maybe find out if this post has any restrictions and if it public or not
No, these posts are random Facebook posts. They weren't created by users who have authenticated in my application

Comment: If these are posts that are not made by users of your application then you do not have the permission to get any information about them via the API. In order to request details about a specific post you need to have permissions to view the content of the page/user where that post was made - without that I'm afraid you're not going to be able to get at this info.

Comment: @Lix: Hmm, maybe I don't understand something. I model the situation - the client sends me through the form URL of his post and I can't get any data from API?

Comment: Indeed - in that situation you'll not be able to get *any* information through the API unless the application accessing the API has the appropriate permissions to view content from that user.

Comment: It's a matter of privacy - you are not able to access every post made on Facebook because some of the posts were made by people who are not your FB friends. Even if they *are* your FB friends you still might not have permission to view that content - the same goes for the API.

Comment: @Lix: Well, for example, I implement authentication for user in my application, now I can get needed data? And how to do this? I mean initial questions about validity URL and post-id